# How do I add a bookmark within the body of a Word doc using Office JS

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

The Office JS has provided the following function in [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#insertbookmark-name-), but I couldn't find any example.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work, any idea what I am missing here, since this code inserts the text but the bookmark is not created.

```
Word.run(function (context)
{
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    return context.sync().then(function ()
    {
        range.insertText(`Test Bookmark`, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

        let uniqueStr = new Date().getTime();
        let bookmarkName = `Test_BookmarkCode_${uniqueStr}`;
        range.insertBookmark(bookmarkName);
    });
});
```

Cross posted [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_365hp/how-do-i-add-a-bookmark-within-the-body-of-a-word/2daf0124-d31b-47a8-a6fc-34b833a73e4a?tm=1591818387408).

Comment: As this is beta preview API, are you referring to the beta CDN?https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Comment: @RaymondLu Yes, I am. <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have tried your code, if i remove this line, it will work, can you have a try? 
       
 ```range.insertText(Test Bookmark`, Word.InsertLocation.replace);```

Comment: @RaymondLu Yes, it worked. Is there a way to add new text and set it as bookmark?

Comment: @RaymondLu I've posted an answer, all I had to do is to use the range returned by range.insertText to insertBookmark.

Comment: Awesome, this is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is the working code. Apparently, when we insertText, a new range is returned, we need to use that range to insertBookmark.

```
Word.run(function (context)
{
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    return context.sync().then(function ()
    {
        let insertedTextRange = range.insertText(`Test Bookmark`, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

        let uniqueStr = new Date().getTime();
        let bookmarkName = `Test_BookmarkCode_${uniqueStr}`;
        insertedTextRange.insertBookmark(bookmarkName);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(Cannot comment, pls excuse my posting this as an answer.) Two things that got in my way when I implemented something similar to the above solution:

1. The bookmark name may not be longer than 40 characters.
2. The name may contain underscores (_), but no dashes (-). Probably most other punctuation characters aren't permitted either.

If you violate either rule you'll get an InvalidArgument exception. I only tried this with the Windows Desktop version of Word 2019, but this behavior is probably the same with other versions.