# Send data to/from Office Online apps

Tags: office-js

New using Office JS. Can I send data among Office Online applications; like for example send a chart from Powerpoint online to Excel online?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike COM add-ins, Office web JS Add-ins don't involve code that runs on the user's device or in the Office client. For an Office Add-in, the host application, for example, Excel, reads the add-in manifest and hooks up the add-in’s custom ribbon buttons and menu commands in the UI. When needed, it loads the add-in's JavaScript and HTML code, which executes in the context of a browser in a sandbox. Therefore, in your descripted scenario Powerpoint Office Web JS add-in could not directly access Excel document.

But if you are using one drive, SharePoint or group drive. there is one solution that I think you could try is to use Excel Graph. via Graph API, You can access a set of Excel objects (such as Table, Range, or Chart) by using standard REST APIs to perform create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations on the workbook. reference document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: can you review my question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263386/how-do-i-add-a-bookmark-within-the-body-of-a-word-doc-using-office-js